# Botframework/Botbuilder-js - Send HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, botframework, chatbot

I created a JavaScript Bot using BotFramework and Botbuilder-js.

For this bot I use an adaptive dialog.
At some point in the dialog I need to send an HTTP-request.

For now, my HTTP-request Step looks like this:

```
new HttpRequest().configure({
    resultProperty: new StringExpression("user.teamProfile.accessToken"),
    url: new StringExpression('https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token'),
    method: HttpMethod.POST,
    contentType: new StringExpression('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": new StringExpression("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    },
    body: new StringExpression("client_id: myClientId, scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, client_secret: myclientSecret, grant_type: client_credentials"),
    responseType: ResponsesTypes.Json
})
```

The bot in itself is working but when it tries to execute the HTTP-Request step, I get the following error message:

```
Error: TypeError: path.indexOf is not a function
```

Unfortunately, I don't get any more information. Can anyone help me ?

Best regards,
BufferOverflow

Comment: Can you link to any samples or documentation you've followed?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Actually no. I changed from HttpRequest to CodeAction. Since I needed work on the request responses, CodeAction was actually the way to go from the beginning.

Comment: Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the HttpRequest-Step didn't work, I changed to a CodeAction.

Inside this CodeAction I then do my Http-Requests and work on the results (transforming them or saving them in a dialog variable).


A Code Snippet could look like the following:

```
new CodeAction(async (dc, options) => {
    // Send your request
    // options being the headers, body, etc.
    const response = await this.fetch(url, options);

    // Work on you result and if necessary, save it to a dialog variable
    dc.state.setValue("user.yourPropertyName", value);

    // Needed for the Bot to continue working
    return await dc.endDialog();
})
```